# Yearly Cohort Analysis in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to make a Cohort Analysis - trying to compute retention. Here is my code:

```
SELECT 
  renter_id,
  min(DATE_PART('year', created_at)) AS first_rental_year,
  DATE_PART('year', created_ay) AS y1,
  round(100 * count(distinct b2.renter_id) /
    count(distinct b1.renter_id)) AS retention      
FROM bookings AS b1
  LEFT JOIN bookings AS b2 ON
    b1.renter_id = b2.renter_id
    AND DATE_PART('year', b1.created_at) = DATE_PART(datetime('year', b2.created_at, '-1 year'))
GROUP BY  1
ORDER BY 2;
```

It's not working at all though ... `The error message I get says: Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Would be awesome with some suggestions.

Comment: what exactly are you trying here `DATE_PART(datetime('year', b2.created_at, '-1 year'))`

Comment: This means "only join rows where the date in b1 is one less than the date in b2", which makes it possible to see if renters have rented more than one time

Comment: as far as i know there is no function in postgresql called datetime...also when you say b1 is less than date in b2, you are doing 1 year less?

Comment: perhaps you are looking for something like this `DATE_PART('year', b1.created_at) = extract(year from b2.created_at)-1`

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem is with the `datetime()` function which does not exist in PostgreSQL. Then there are some issues with aliases and aggregates. This should get you closer to where you want to be:

```
SELECT 
  b1.renter_id,
  min(DATE_PART('year', b1.created_at)) AS first_rental_year,
  DATE_PART('year', created_ay) AS y1,            -- Needs an aggregate
  round(100. * count(distinct b2.renter_id) /     -- Use float, see 100.
    count(distinct b1.renter_id)) AS retention
FROM bookings AS b1
LEFT JOIN bookings AS b2
  ON  b1.renter_id = b2.renter_id
  AND extract(year, b1.created_at) + 1 = extract(year, b2.created_at)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2;
```

However, the logic of your cohort function *appears* to be flawed. You should edit your question to:

1. Explain in more detail how you want to calculate retention
2. Add table structures and some sample data
3. Show expected result.

Comment: 1. I want to figure out how well/bad we are retaining renters by their first rental year. So, are we retaining renters whose first rental year was 2013 better than people whose first rental year was 2015?
2. https://gyazo.com/f0b3cf7cdca0384d7090fe34b3ab0264
3. See 2.